# Running into an infinite loop while solving CryptArithmetic Problem in Python

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking

I am solving a problem from LeetCode, https://leetcode.com/problems/verbal-arithmetic-puzzle/ using Backtracking.

This is the same as CryptArithmetic problem, so I will explain in short what the problem exactly is.

[image: This Image explains the question and the desired output]

```
class Solution:
    def isSolvable(self,words, result):
        characterMap={}
        uniqueString=""

        for word in words:
            for letter in word:
                if letter not in characterMap:
                    uniqueString+=letter
                    characterMap[letter]=-1
        
        for r in result:
            if r not in characterMap:
                uniqueString+=r
                characterMap[r]=-1
        
                
        self.words=words
        self.result=result
        self.uniqueString=uniqueString
        self.characterMap=characterMap
        self.usedDigit={i:False for i in range(10)}

        
        return self.isSolvableHelper(0)
    
    def getSum(self, word):
        sums=""
        for w in word:
            sums+=str(self.characterMap[w])
        
        return int(sums)
    
    def isSolvableHelper(self, idx):
        if(idx==len(self.uniqueString)):
            sumUp=0
            for w in self.words:
                sumUp+=self.getSum(w)
            
            resultSum=self.getSum(self.result)
            
            return True if(resultSum==sumUp) else False
        
        char=self.uniqueString[idx]
        for i in range(10):
            if(not self.usedDigit[i]):
                self.characterMap[char]=i
                self.usedDigit[i]=True
                self.isSolvableHelper(idx+1)
                self.usedDigit[i]=False
                self.characterMap[char]=-1

sol=Solution()
sol.isSolvable(['SEND','MORE'], "MONEY")
```

I have considered the same example as input where the words array/list = `["SEND", "MORE"]` and the result is `MONEY`

I run into an inifinite loop not sure where this happens, I suspect
that its probably the block where the backtracking begins
This is the output, it just goes on running
[image]

can you help me to know whats the mistake in my logic here.

Comment: Could you please post a [mre]? In particular, what is the input of your functions that result in the infinite loop? Also, what makes you think that the infinite loop happens on that line of code precisely?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question, added the problem statement and the output displayed in my console, suspecting the backtracking block is where the problem lies

Comment: Not sure it is looping : the number of possibilities for the code is factorial of 10 / factorial (10 - len(unique string) which is quite a lot. For first example : 10!/(10-2)!=10!/2!=10*9*7*6*5*4*3 = 1814400. as length of string is 8.

Comment: Is this using backtracking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never return True when you find a solution : in isSolvableHelper :

```
            for i in range(10):
                if(not self.usedDigit[i]):
                    self.characterMap[char]=i
                    self.usedDigit[i]=True
                    # in the next line you do not test the returned value, so you do not know when you have finished
                    self.isSolvableHelper(idx+1)
                    self.usedDigit[i]=False
                    self.characterMap[char]=-1
```

Add a test :

```
            for i in range(10):
                if(not self.usedDigit[i]):
                    self.characterMap[char]=i
                    self.usedDigit[i]=True
                    If  self.isSolvableHelper(idx+1):
                        return True
                    self.usedDigit[i]=False
                    self.characterMap[char]=-1
            # Do not forget to return False 
            return False
```

You can also optimise getSum by using only integers :

```
    def getSum(self, word):
        #print("getSum({})".format(word))
        sums=0
        for w in word:
            sums = 10 * sums + self.characterMap[w]
    
        return sums
```

Some results : (one loop = one entry in isSolvableHelper)

```
SEND MORE = MONEY
Char map : {'E': 8, 'D': 7, 'M': 0, 'O': 3, 'N': 1, 'S': 2, 'R': 6, 'Y': 5}
nb loop : 730250

SIX SEVEN SEVEN = TWENTY
Char Mao : {'E': 8, 'I': 5, 'N': 2, 'S': 6, 'T': 1, 'W': 3, 'V': 7, 'Y': 4, 'X': 0}
nb loop : 4094645

THIS IS TOO = FUNNY
Char map : {'F': 0, 'I': 8, 'H': 6, 'O': 5, 'N': 1, 'S': 2, 'U': 4, 'T': 3, 'Y': 9}
nb loop : 2272068

LEET CODE = POINT
no char map
nb loop : 6235301
```

Comment: Thank You @Ptit Xav, This worked, I am just getting started with the concept of Backtracking and this helped me a lot.